# JavaScript - Building JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to understand how to build a JSON object in JavaScript. This JSON object will get passed to a JQuery ajax call. Currently, I'm hard-coding my JSON and making my JQuery call as shown here:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/services/myService.svc/PostComment",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: '{"comments":"test","priority":"1"}',
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (res) {
    alert("Thank you!");
  },
  error: function (req, msg, obj) {
    alert("There was an error");
  }
});
```

This approach works. But, I need to dynamically build my JSON and pass it onto the JQuery call. However, I cannot figure out how to dynamically build the JSON object. Currently, I'm trying the following without any luck:

```
var comments = $("#commentText").val();
var priority = $("#priority").val();
var json = { "comments":comments,"priority":priority };

$.ajax({
  url: "/services/myService.svc/PostComment",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: json,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (res) {
    alert("Thank you!");
  },
  error: function (req, msg, obj) {
    alert("There was an error");
  }
});
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I noticed that with the second version, my service is not even getting reached.

Thank you

Comment: Do you get any Javascript errors?

Comment: Excellent point - try running this with the Firebug debugger turned on and see what you get.

Comment: I am not getting any JavaScript errors. The error event handler in my $.ajax call is getting triggered though.

Comment: Well there you go... what error message are you getting back? Is it helpful?

Comment: Doh! It was a type mismatch issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to look at the [JSON JavaScript library](http://www.json.org/js.html). It has a `stringify()` function which I think will do exactly what you need.

Comment: That's what I thought initially, but from the code he is using in his example, jQuery is supposed to take care of this for you.

Comment: @Justin Ethier: no, jQuery has no JSON serialization (only deserialization). jQuery does something completely different with the data object @user208662 is passing to it.

Comment: @Crescent Fresh: the docs (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) have an example of doing `data: ({id : this.getAttribute('id')})`

Comment: Exactly. I use the same syntax in my application and it works just fine without `stringify` (which is still useful elsewhere, of course).

Comment: @Mark, @Justin Ethier: again, jQuery does not use JSON serialization. The data object passed in @Mark's example and answer simply gets routed to `jQuery.param()` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/), a different kind of serialization altogether.

Comment: @Crescent Fresh: I see. One passes the entire string, which happens to be a JSON object, and the other will create a set of name/value parameters from the JSON object you give it.

Answer (score 6):

Your code:

```
var comments = $("#commentText").val();
var priority = $("#priority").val();
var json = { "comments":comments,"priority":priority };
```

Take out the quotes ( line 3 ):

```
var comments = $("#commentText").val();
var priority = $("#priority").val();
var json = { comments: comments, priority: priority };
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the quotes

```
data: '{"comments":"test","priority":"1"}',
```

becomes

```
data: {"comments":"test","priority":"1"},
```

JSONs are objects not strings.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
var json = { comments: "comments",priority: "priority" };
```

Comment: As far as I understand it, in JSON all strings need to be double quoted, so "comments" and "priority".  That is a Javascript object, so if you were trying to show just a Javascript object, it is valid.  For the JSON format, though, strings need double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

this works for me.

```
var json = "{ 'comments': '" + *comments* +"','priority:' '" + *priority* +"' }";
```

italics are the variables.

Comment: What happens if the comments and priority variables also includes double quotes? This fails. Not the ideal solution.